# Is it possible to prototype server/SQL performance on paper for various loads?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am trying to figure out whether a web development project is feasible at the moment and have so far learned that the total row count of the proposed database (30 million rows, 5 columns and about 3 gb of storage) is well within the budget limits in terms of storage requirements, but because of the anticipated large number of queries that users will make to the database I am not sure if this will cause an unrealistic load to manage for the server to provide adequate performance (within my budget).

I will be using this grid (a live demo of performance benchmarks for 300,000 rows - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/performance/linq/defaultcs.aspx).  Inserting a search term in the "product name" box and pressing enter takes 1.6 seconds from query to results render. It seems to me (a newbie) that 300,000 rows which take 1.6 seconds all in all must take much longer with 30 million rows, and so I am trying to figure out

- what the increase in time would be the more rows are added up to 30 million
- what the increase in time would be for each additional 1000 people using the search grid at the same time.
- what hardware requirements are necessary to reduce the delays to an acceptable level

Hopefully if I can figure that out I can get a more realistic assessment for feasibility. FYI: The database need not be updated very regularly, it is more for readonly purposes.

Can this problem be prototyped on paper for these 3 points?

*Even wide ball park estimates- without considering optimisation, am I talking hundreds of dollars for 5000 users to have searches below 10 seconds each, thousands, or tens of thousands of dollars?*

[Will be asp.net RadControls for AJAX Grid, One of these cloud hosted servers:  4,096MB RAM
160GB Diskspace, and either Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012 ]

Comment: You have left out some important considerations. What is the schema including indexing, what is the cardinality of the data, what is the DAL? Consider all of those before you even think about hardware. The discontinued flag is probably going to be the killer - store that as `DiscontinuedDate` so it can be indexed well.

Comment: There will be a unique ID column for each row, it is basically an item list with 5 columns of data including price, size, picture URL etc..  Nothing too fancy.  Can we assume that proper indexing and DB design are optimal? I only need a rough estimate with simple data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The database need not be updated very regularly, it is more for readonly purposes.

Your search filters allow for substring searches, so db indexes are not going to help you and the search will go row-by-row.

It looks like your data would probably fit in 5GB of memory or so. I would store the whole thing in memory and seach there.

Comment: Thanks RedFilter (sighs with relief finally!) I have just come off the phone with a server provider and they couldn't tell me what I needed saying I needed to workout what throughput the server would use? He described it being the number of concurrent connections to the database- but something I don't understand is if it takes 1.6 seconds for one user to search, why wouldn't it take 3.2 seconds for 2 users? Does the database store the results in memory generally so that other users searching make use of the same 'results' or something?

Comment: *My worry still is that if I had 10,000 searches happening roughly at the same time, does that mean I need many more gigs of RAM, or does it mean each user waits longer? Or what actually happens and what it means for server upgrades etc.?

Comment: In general, if you receive a Burst arrival of requests and this amount goes beyond the offered system load (number of connections, threads, memory etc) your system will become unstable and crash. You would need an input flow control e.g. a queue or drop jobs if the load is higher than the system capacity but again, you need to make an analytical model e.g. M/M/1 Queue to find out what your offered system capacity is. This is like asking how can I make sure that particles collide properly at CERN without knowing anything about Physics ...